# Spring boot - WebFlux - WebTestClient - convert response to responseEntity

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, webtestclient, spring-webtestclient

I have a Reactive controller which returns:

```java
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/data")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Data>> getData() {
  //service call which returns Mono<Data> dataMono
  Mono<ResponseEntity<Data>> responseEntityMono = dataMono
          .map(data -> ResponseEntity.ok(data))
          .doFinally(signalType -> {});

  return responseEntityMono;
}
```

I am using `WebTestClient` to test this endpoint, but I want to extract the response entity for cucumber to validate further.

I tried this:

```java
@Autowired private WebTestClient webTestClient;

public ResponseEntity get() {
  EntityExchangeResult < ResponseEntity > response = webTestClient.get()
    .uri(uriBuilder ->
      uriBuilder
      .path(VISUALIZATION_URL)
      .build())
    .header("Accepts", "application/json")
    .exchange()
    .expectStatus().isOk()
    .expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    .expectBody(ResponseEntity.class)
    .returnResult();
  return response.getResponseBody();
}
```

but I am getting an error. I can get the JSON by doing:

```java
public String get() {
  BodyContentSpec bodyContentSpec = webTestClient.get()
    .uri(uriBuilder ->
      uriBuilder
      .path(URL)
      .build())
    .header("Accepts", "application/json")
    .exchange()
    .expectStatus().isOk()
    .expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    .expectBody();
  return new String(bodyContentSpec.returnResult().getResponseBody());
}
```

But I am trying to see if I can get the whole `ResponseEntity` so that I can validate headers, caching headers, and body.

Comment: Please do not write `but I am getting error` this kind of statement is not helpful at all. Please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

You will never be able to get a `ResponseEntity` in your test. `WebTestClient.ResponseSpec` returned from `exchange()` is the only way to check the answer from your Controller. `ResponseEntity` is just the object you return in your method but once Jackson serializes it, it is converted to a regular HTTP response (in your case with JSON in his body and regular HTTP headers).